# Is it possible to ignore Nyquist-Shannon theorem?

Tags: math, physics, analysis

I have a case in which I have to find a frequency of wavering object with camera (some kind of visual odometry). There is a limitation: frequency of a filming camera (fps) should be at least twice high as frequency of wavering object. Are there any possible ways to take the readings of frequencies exceed this limit? I was thinking about accumulating data and then doing some maths on this.

Comment: You can somewhat get around the sampling theorem if you can make some particular assumptions about the frequency content of the signal you're measuring. For example, for perfectly periodic signals, take a look at how equivalent time sampling oscilloscopes work. For bandpass signals, take a look at subsampling techniques. If your signal truly has frequency content ranging from DC all the way to the bandwidth, you may be out of luck.

Comment: The theorem says what it says, and nothing more.  If your signal is periodic, for example, you don't need to sample at a rate corresponding to the highest harmonic component of the signal, rather, you can equivalent-time sample it by taking down points infrequently (noting their time relative to start), and reconstructing the waveform. This effectively splits your bandwidth into narrow slices overlapping the signal and harmonics, with wide gaps inbetween.

Comment: You don't have to pay any attention to it, but it will still apply. It's a mathematical theorem, one of the few things that's actually exact. Of course, you might not be interpreting the theorem correctly, as well. Remember it talks about *bandwidth*, which doesn't have to be based at DC, if you have a valid range of frequencies that doesn't include DC, and can band-limit your signal to avoid aliasing.

Comment: wild thought: depending on the type of sensor you will have issues like rolling shutter. If you know the speed at which each "pixel" line is sampled you might be able to get the speed of an object.

Comment: _"frequency of a **filming** camera"_ - what does this mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott i meant fps but wrote it in a strange way

Comment: @WesleyLee the camera wouldn't have this effect cause the sensor has a global shutter

Answer (score 4):

> *I was thinking about accumulating data and then doing some maths on
> this.*

How would you figure-out which frequency produced the samples (black dots): -

[image]

Blue is over-sampled and red is under-sampled.

---

**Footnote**

On a job I was involved with, a turbine rotor was checked for blade vibration. The measurement "device" sat at one point on the turbine casing and, single spot-measurements were made for each passing blade. If a particular blade arrived a little early or a little late, it could be construed that it was excessively vibrating. The blades were grossly under-sampled compared to their vibration frequency but, useful data was gathered.

I'm only giving you the bare bones story here and not explaining how each blade's data could be uniquely identified.

Comment: You could by *assuming* that the actual signal is within a certain limited range of frequencies. If it is true, of course.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes you could do that but, my answer is really trying to get the OP to think about what he's asking.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about this issue. Im just taking into account that this technique wouldn't work for frequencies with the same phase. But for other frequencies with different phases the situation is going to be different: i want to do something similar to a equivalent time sampling method but instead of simultaneous measurement im going to "manually" put some segments of data on another segments (and merge them somehow) until i'll be able to fit a sine wave to it

Comment: Two different frequencies can't be realistically said to have the same phase angle except when both pass through zero at the same time and this may never happen, happen quite regularly or happen fairly infrequently so, maybe you need to dig a little deeper here @ureadulose <-- phase angle is not relevant to any analysis I suspect.